# How to use any Internet connection in Android app (wifi, 3g, 4g, etc)?

Tags: android, network-programming, wifi, 3g

I am writing an app that requires using the Internet. Some relevant bits of code that I have are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and

```
private boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        // do stuff
        return true;
    }
    else{
        // don't do stuff and display dialog instead
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, my app only seems to work on a WiFi connection. How do I make it work regardless of how it connects to the Internet?

Comment: You should use isConnectedOrConnecting() instead of isConnected()

Comment: Also. I never check if the user is connected, cause when you want to do network stuff and the user isn't connected it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public class NetWorkCheck{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo, lanInfo;


    public Boolean checkNow(Context con){

        try{
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);


            if(wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("CheckConnectivity Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and in the Activity that u want to test connection write this code

```
 NetWorkCheck networkCheck = new NetWorkCheck();
 boolean connection;

connection = networkCheck.checkNow(UpdateVehicleDetails.this);
                if (connection) {
```